# How can I update rows obtained by a SELECT query in PostgreSQL with Python? Python 2.7 psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have the following code to calculate a value in specific rows of my table:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE license_type_code='20' ORDER BY general_score DESC;")
group_size = cursor.rowcount
for record in cursor:
   index = cursor.rownumber
   percentile = 100*(index - 0.5)/group_size
   print percentile
```

What I need to do is to add the `percentile` result to the respective column `score_percentile` of each record I got with the `SELECT` query.

I thought about an `UPDATE` query like this:

```
 cursor.execute("UPDATE restaurants SET score_percentile="+str(percentile)+" WHERE license_type_code IN (SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE license_type_code='20' ORDER BY general_score DESC)")
```

But I don't know if that query is correct or if there's a more efficient and less silly way to do that (I'm sure there has to be).
Could you help me, please?

I'm new with SQL so any help or advice is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas said, I just needed an update query with the following syntax:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE restaurants f SET score_percentile = ROUND(100*(f2.rownumber - 0.5)/"+str(group_size)+",3) FROM (SELECT f2.*,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY general_score DESC) as rownumber FROM restaurants f2 WHERE license_type_code='20') f2 WHERE f.license_type_code='20' AND f2.license_number=f.license_number;")
```

And I got the `group_size` by:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM restaurants WHERE license_type_code='20'")
group_size = cursor.fetchone()
group_size = group_size[0]
```

That worked perfect for my case

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop at all. Just one update query

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE restaurants SET score_percentile = 100*(rownumber - 0.5)/group_size  FROM (SELECT COUNT (*) as group_size FROM restaurants WHERE license_type_code='20') as t WHERE restaurants.license_type_code='20'")
```

Comment: Although the syntax of your query does not work, you gave me the insight of how to solve it. Thanks!